# Will accesing static object/resources through static methods have performance issue?

Tags: java, multithreading, static-methods, static-members

I have a class which reads an xml file and populates them in a private static data-structure(say, HashMap). This initial population happens in a static block. Then I have method to get value of a given key, which intern refers that static HashMap. Cosider the case, when multiple threads tries to get value for a given key, will there be any performance hit; like, when one thread is reading that static object other threads has to wait.

```
  public class Parser
  {
       private static HashMap resource = new HashMap();

       static
       {
         parseResource();
       }

       private Parser()
       {
       }

       private static parseResource()
       {
           //parses the resource and populates the resource object
       }

       public static Object getValue( String key)
       {
           //may be some check will be done here, but not any     
           //update/modification actions
          return resource.get(key);
       }    
   }
```

Comment: As long as the reading process is not defined as synchronized, the threads won't wait for other threads for completion.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it's worth being aware that this really has very little to do with `static`. There's no such thing as a "static object" - there are just objects, and there are fields and methods which may or may not be static. For example, there could be an instance field and a static field which both refer to the same object.

In terms of thread safety, you need to consider the safety of the operations you're interested in on a single object - it doesn't matter how the multiple threads have "reached" that object.

> like, when one thread is reading that static object other threads has to wait.

No, it doesn't.

If you are *just* reading from the `HashMap` after constructing it in a way that prevented it from being visible to other threads until it had been finished, that's fine. (Having reread your comment, it looks like that's the case in `getValue`.)

If you need to perform any mutations on the map while other threads are reading from it, consider using [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) or use synchronization.

From the [docs for `HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally.

Comment: For completeness I'd suggest you lookup good practices for implementing Singletons. In Java 6 and after you can use an Enum (the recommended way to write Singletons) to correctly encapsulate the initialized read only data.

Answer (score 0):

You have no locking happening in your example code, so there's no way that multiple threads would need to wait.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to Jon Skeet's answer, for this kind of use you might want to consider Guava's [ImmutableMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html), which enforces immutability.

Answer (score -1):

Just use the [synchronized](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) keyword and everything should work fine.

Comment: `HashMap` is safe for *reading* from multiple threads, so there's no need to synchronize.